# nginx short url not quite getting me there

Tags: mediawiki

I am setting up mediawiki on my site and want to use short urls at the root.  I want my address to be:

wiki.example.com/Main_Page, wiki.exampe.com/another_page

main site redirect goal:

wiki.example.com  --> wiki.example.com/Main_Page

not:

wiki.example.com  --> wiki.example.com/**Wiki**/Main_Page

to reiterate if i type wiki.example.com/Main_Page i get where I am supposed to be.

if I type wiki.example.com I get to wiki.example.com/Wiki/Main_Page which does not exist.

I have made the following modifications to my LocalSettings.php

```
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
```

I don't know where the Wiki/ in Wiki/Main_Page is comming form.

I would really appreciate any help you can send my way to get this working how I'd like.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That redirect comes from MediaWiki, not nginx. Fix the MediaWiki configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I looked in LocalSettings.php and do not see anything, Am I looking in the correct config?  if so I can post some of that.